# Using AJAX to send data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This must be the most asked question around here, but I have been scratching my head for an hour now and I cannot figure out why my data does not make it to the server side.

My HTML where I have a simple table and my goal is to have all users in the table and for each row there is a link which redirects to another PHP page which should query some data according to the specific username to which the row corresponds to:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/psl-config.php';
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include 'includes/functions.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Individual Data</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ind.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="highscore">
    <tr id='title'>
        <th></th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Trials</th>
        <th>RDM</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $scores = getTopScores($mysqli);
        $nr = 1;
        foreach($scores as $row){
            echo '<tr id="highscore"><td id="id">'.$nr.'.'.'</td><td id="username">'.$row['username'].'</td><td>'.$row['trial'].'</td>'.'<td><a id="irdm" href="individualRDM.php">RDM</a></td></tr>';
            $nr+=1;
        }
    ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript where I send the data:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('a#irdm').click(function(){
        var $item = $(this).closest("tr")
                       .find("#username")
                       .text(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'individualRDM.php',
        data: {
            username: "test"
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });


    });
});
```

This is the PHP file where I would like to see the data:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/psl-config.php';
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    print $username;
}
else 
{
  echo "No username supplied";
}
?>
```

The problem right now is that $_POST variable is completely empty. I'm sorry if this probably is a duplicate of every other Ajax related question, but I've been through many of them and I still cannot solve it. Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: check your console, check for errors (PHP/MySQL).

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: your console may not contain errors, but your PHP/MySQL might. that's what the latter part of my comment meant ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but none that I can see

Comment: Try the code below:
 

    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'individualRDM.php',
            data: 'username=test',
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
            }
        });

Comment: Still nothing, I'm guessing it is something really stupid I'm not seeing.

Comment: and you're sure that your query didn't fail you... try a pure PHP method, if it works, it's your JS. If it doesn't, it's your query. NullPoiиteя closed your question as being JS related, so that person must've spotted someting in your JS. I'm mostly a PHP/MySQL guy. JS isn't my strong point.